# Machine learning regressor for cyclic values

Tags: machine-learning, circular-statistics

I have a question regarding training a Machine Learning regressor for cyclic values. For instance, consider phase values. We cannot use conventional regression methods for this as for example the difference between 1 degree and 359 degrees is not in fact 358 degrees!
What tricks should one use to train the machine learning regressors for cyclic values? Should we consider sin or cos of the angle instead of the angle itself for instance?
Any ideas/references are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What an interesting problem! For this cyclical problem, do you have any mirroring? For example, is 0 functionally the same to you as 180? or 90 and 270? Or for the problem, is there genuinely a need to differentiate all parts of the cycle from one another (90 is distinct from 270, 0 distinct from 180)?

Comment: Thank you for your response @VladimirBelik. For me 180 and 0 are different. I think 90 and 270 also should be different in my application.  I think the only problem for me is when we add/subtract 2*pi to/from the response in cyclic motion. For instance, you can consider the 1 and 359 example that I mentioned above.

Comment: Is it the *response* or an *explanatory variable* that is cyclic?  You can find many answers to your question by clicking through the [tag:circular-statistics] tag you have (correctly) applied to this post.